# can't see paypal payment option in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

I made a change in /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php file

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

Changed code,

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'INR');
```

since this change i can't see paypal payment option anywhere in my magento admin panel.

I even revert the changes, clean the cache, re-index file but still no luck.

[image]

Comment: Do you have developer-mode enabled and logging turned on and checked exception.log and system.log?

Answer (score 3):

Something else has to be wrong with your code.

## 1 - Never edit core code, that is the #1 sin for Magento Developers.

There are two ways to edit this file, either create a module that rewrites that function (best way), or take this file "app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php" and copy it to "app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php".

I have gone ahead and downloaded a fresh copy of CE1.7.0.2 and made the change you said you changed. After flushing cache, I am still able to see the PayPal methods in the payment section.

[image: Screenshot after the change]

The screenshot you have posted is actually a little odd. The "Merchant Location" is actually apart of the PayPal extension (see app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/system.xml) so I know that the PayPal extension is somewhat loading.

So lets take a stab at debugging the issue at hand. First off, in the index.php, I want you to edit lines 73-77.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
 
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Then change it to this:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will turn on developers mode.

Then, in the backend, go to System -> Configuration -> Developer (left hand tab), then turn on logging and hit save.

[image: Enable Logging]

Once both of these changes are in place, I want you to go back to the "Payment Methods" again and refresh the page. Check to see if there are any errors that show up on the screen, then check to see if you can find any errors in the folder "var/log". You may see a system.log and a exception.log.

If nothing turns up in the logs, its time to diff your code. You will need a program like "DiffMerge" (it is free). Once you install that program, you will need to download from the Magento website a clean copy of the code (make sure it is the same version number you are running).

This will search the code to see what else has changed in the core code. Hopefully you haven't edited other core code.

If you are unable to find the issue at this point, it could either mean a issue with the database (unlikely, however I have seen stranger issues), or a issue with a 3rd party extension. The next steps at that point would be to go to a clean copy of Magento using the same database and see it will appear (with none of your 3rd party extensions).

Answer (score 1):

there is no these type of lines in `system.xml` file.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```